# Primeng split button add icon on select

Tags: angular, primeng

i would like to add tick icon once user selected the click option in split button.
How can be achievable? Please advise me.Thanks
Example like below -

[image]

Comment: anyone can assist on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround solution, I'll try to explain my solution and I'll give you a stackblitz link:

First, you should create new type which extends the `MenuItem` interface:

```
type MenuItemWithSelection = MenuItem & {
  isSelected?: boolean;
};
```

By doing so, you can add `isSelected` property for each item and check that to know which item is selected. Also you should add `id` property on each item in order to get element by id and add the tick icon after the item label.

Then, you should create a function which create the icon after the label of the item:

```
  /**
   * Creates a tick icon for the specified element ID.
   * @param elId - The ID of the element for which to create the tick icon.
   */
  createTickIcon(elId: string) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const el = document.getElementById(elId);

      // Check if the element exists
      if (el) {
        // Get the last child element (assumed to be the label of the item)
        const text = el.lastElementChild;

        // Unicode for the tick icon
        const icon = '\ue909';

        // Set the data attribute for the tick icon on the text element to use it as content after the text
        text.setAttribute('data-tick-icon', icon);
      }
    }, 0);
  }
```

Now you need a function to handle the selection logic to know when you should create the tick icon:

```
  /**
   * Selects an item by its ID, updates the selection status, and creates a check icon if selected.
   * @param elId - The ID of the element to be selected.
   */
  selectAndCreateCheckIcon(elId: string) {
    const selectedItem = this.items.find((el) => el.id === elId);

    // Deselect all other items
    this.items.forEach((el) => {
      if (el.id !== elId) {
        el.isSelected = false;
      }
    });

    // Update the selection status and create a check icon if the item is found
    if (selectedItem) {
      selectedItem.isSelected = !selectedItem.isSelected;

      // If the item is selected, create a check icon
      if (selectedItem.isSelected) {
        this.createTickIcon(elId);
      }
    }
  }
```

Absolutely you noticed, the modal in the split button closed immediately after click on any item so you need to create icon on the modal show you can handle that be using this function:

```
  /**
   * Handles the click event on the dropdown when show the menu.
   * Finds the selected item and creates a tick icon for it.
   */
  onDropdownClick() {
    // Find the selected item
    const selectedElement = this.items.find((element) => element.isSelected);

    // Check if a selected item exists
    if (selectedElement) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Create a tick icon for the selected item
        this.createTickIcon(selectedElement.id);
      }, 0);
    }
  }
```

I know it's a little bit tedious solution but, you can encapsulate this functionality in a class like below and use this class to create a split button with selection feature:

```
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';

type MenuItemWithSelection = MenuItem & {
  isSelected?: boolean;
};

export class SplitButtonWithTick {
  items: MenuItemWithSelection[];

  /**
   * Handles the click event on the dropdown when show the menu.
   * Finds the selected item and creates a tick icon for it.
   */
  onDropdownClick() {
    // Find the selected item
    const selectedElement = this.items.find((element) => element.isSelected);

    // Check if a selected item exists
    if (selectedElement) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Create a tick icon for the selected item
        this.createTickIcon(selectedElement.id);
      }, 0);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Creates a tick icon for the specified element ID.
   * @param elId - The ID of the element for which to create the tick icon.
   */
  createTickIcon(elId: string) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const el = document.getElementById(elId);

      // Check if the element exists
      if (el) {
        // Get the last child element (assumed to be the text of the item)
        const text = el.lastElementChild;

        // Unicode for the tick icon
        const icon = '\ue909';

        // Set the data attribute for the tick icon on the text element to use it as content after the text
        text.setAttribute('data-tick-icon', icon);
      }
    }, 0);
  }

  /**
   * Selects an item by its ID, updates the selection status, and creates a check icon if selected.
   * @param elId - The ID of the element to be selected.
   */
  selectAndCreateCheckIcon(elId: string) {
    const selectedItem = this.items.find((el) => el.id === elId);

    // Deselect all other items
    this.items.forEach((el) => {
      if (el.id !== elId) {
        el.isSelected = false;
      }
    });

    // Update the selection status and create a check icon if the item is found
    if (selectedItem) {
      selectedItem.isSelected = !selectedItem.isSelected;

      // If the item is selected, create a check icon
      if (selectedItem.isSelected) {
        this.createTickIcon(elId);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now in your component just create instance of this class :

```
  splitButton: SplitButtonWithTick = new SplitButtonWithTick();
```

And define the items like that:

```
   this.splitButton.items = [
      {
        label: 'Update',
        icon: 'pi pi-refresh',
        command: () => {
          this.update();
          //add this to add check icon
          this.splitButton.selectAndCreateCheckIcon('updateId');
        },
        id: 'updateId',
        isSelected: false,
      },
      {
        label: 'Delete',
        icon: 'pi pi-times',
        command: () => {
          this.delete();
          this.splitButton.selectAndCreateCheckIcon('deleteId');
        },
        id: 'deleteId',
        isSelected: false,
      },
      {
        label: 'Angular.io',
        icon: 'pi pi-info',
        url: 'http://angular.io',
        id: 'angularId',
        command: () => {
          this.splitButton.selectAndCreateCheckIcon('angularId');
        },
        isSelected: false,
      },
      { separator: true },
      {
        label: 'Setup',
        icon: 'pi pi-cog',
        routerLink: ['/setup'],
        id: 'cogId',
        command: () => {
          this.splitButton.selectAndCreateCheckIcon('cogId');
        },
        isSelected: false,
      },
    ];
```

In your html:

```
<h5>Basic</h5>
<p-splitButton
  label="Save"
  icon="pi pi-plus"
  (onClick)="save('info')"
  (onDropdownClick)="splitButton.onDropdownClick()"
  [model]="splitButton.items"
></p-splitButton>
```

**The most important part in this solution is the CSS**:

```
.p-menuitem-text::after {
 //if it doesn't work add :host ::ng-deep before .p-menuitem-text
  content: attr(data-tick-icon);
  font-family: 'primeicons' !important;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

This is the `stackblitz` link:
[Add tick icon when select item](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-splitbutton-demo-ku1hxa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fsplit-button-with-tick.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: hi Mouayad, thanks for the reply and sorry for the delay reply. i am not there is reply for this. will try this and get back to you soon. Thanks mate!